# How to remove element from div in js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have list of descriptions and after remove one of them, I'd like to remove that element from div (one element from list of descriptions), not refreshing site. So I'd like to ask how should my destroy.js.erb looks like?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="box">
                 <div class="descriptions">
                      <%= render @descriptions %> 
                  </div>
        </div>
</div>

//_description.html.erb
<div class="description-field">
  <%= @description.text %>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you paste the complete block of descriptions in HTML? including the main div in which descriptions HTML will be included?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using jQuery because you are using Rails, you could potentially do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="descriptions">
      <p class="remove-descriptions">
        <%= render @descriptions %>
      </p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//_description.html.erb
<div class="description-field">
  <p class="remove-descriptions">
    <%= @description.text %>
  </p>
</div>
```

You could then use jQuery to remove that element from `<div class="descriptions">` with the following:

```
$('.remove-descriptions').remove();
```

**Result in DOM:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="descriptions">           
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//_description.html.erb
<div class="description-field">      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery .remove

example form jquery reference

html page

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="hello">Hello</div>
   <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

javascript  jquery (remove the element wiht the class "hello"

```
 $( ".hello" ).remove();
```

result ind DOM

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With JavaScript** Using [remove()](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#childnode)

**Answer:1**

You can remove elements like this:

`document.getElementById("my-element").remove();`

**Answer:2** [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div-01">Here is div-01</div>
<div id="div-02">Here is div-02</div>
<div id="div-03">Here is div-03</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('div-01');
el.nextElementSibling.remove(); // Removes the div with the 'div-02' id
```